# В чем разница между WHERE и HAVING в PostgreSQL?

Tags: sql, postgresql

Какая разница в поведении при использовании в запросе к таблице PostgreSQL ключевых слов WHERE и HAVING?

Comment: с таким успехом мы можем всю документацию переписать на SO! Вы искать пробовали?  [вторая ссылка по запросу where having sql](https://ru.wikipedia.org/wiki/Having_(SQL))

Answer (score 6, accepted):

> Основное отличие WHERE от HAVING заключается в том, что WHERE сначала выбирает строки, а затем группирует их и вычисляет агрегатные функции (таким образом, она отбирает строки для вычисления агрегатов), тогда как HAVING отбирает строки групп после группировки и вычисления агрегатных функций. Как следствие, предложение WHERE не должно содержать агрегатных функций; не имеет смысла использовать агрегатные функции для определения строк для вычисления агрегатных функций. Предложение HAVING, напротив, всегда содержит агрегатные функции. (Строго говоря, вы можете написать предложение HAVING, не используя агрегаты, но это редко бывает полезно. То же самое условие может работать более эффективно на стадии WHERE.)

— [Документация PostgreSQL 9.6: Aggregate functions](https://www.postgresql.org/docs/9.6/static/tutorial-agg.html) ([она же на русском](https://postgrespro.ru/docs/postgrespro/9.6/tutorial-agg))

Comment: *вы можете написать предложение HAVING, не используя агрегаты, но это редко бывает полезно* Это полезно, когда нужно выполнять отбор по выражению выходного набора - в HAVING можно ссылаться на поля выходного набора по их именам, а вот во WHERE придётся писать то же выражение ещё раз.

Comment: @Akina ...что в некоторых случаях может вызвать замедление, если я верно интерпретирую документацию.

Answer (score 5):

HAVING аналогичен WHERE за исключением того, что строки отбираются не по значениям столбцов, а строятся из значений столбцов, указанных в GROUP BY, и значений агрегатных функций, вычисленных для каждой группы, образованной GROUP BY.